# Actionlistener of a Timer object displays nothing

Tags: java, timer

i am usin the `timer` class and in the docs it is written that i should import `javax.swing.Timer` to use it. does it mean that i can not use it in my normal java file? because i tried the below code, and it displays nothing:

```
static ActionListener timeStampListener = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("action listener");
        for (int i = 1; i <= logfile.getTotalLines(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Engine Time(ms): " +  
            logfile.getFileHash().get(i).getTimeStampInSec());
        }
    }
};

    Timer t = new Timer(2, timeStampListener);
    t.setRepeats(true);
    t.start();
```

Comment: I have the same problem so when I use `Thread.sleep(interval)`     my code works.

Comment: I want to make it clear. I had the same question for my assignment and my teacher asked us to add `JOptionPane` and `System.exit(0)` at the end of the code in order to prevent program to get closed. you could also use `scanner` to keep your program waiting. I think it is easier to understand rather than using `thread.sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your main thread exist before starting timer thread .since your application is non-gui use `util.Timer` instead `Swing.Timer` ..if you want to work this code using swing timer then add a swing component  .add `new jframe()` and see it's working ..you don't need swing.timer use util timer .

```
   static ActionListener timeStampListener1 = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrame(); //add this line
        Timer t = new Timer(2, timeStampListener1);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();

    }
```

or give some times by adding `thread.sleep` to timer to on and see it's working

```
    Timer t = new Timer(2, timeStampListener1);
    t.setRepeats(true);
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

---

this is how can u use util timer for this

imports

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("action listener");
                for (int i = 1; i <= logfile.getTotalLines(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Engine Time(ms): "
                            + logfile.getFileHash().get(i).getTimeStampInSec());
                }
            }
        }, 500, 2);
    }
```

Comment: thank you. but without importing .swing.timer the timer with two parameters is undefined and unrecognised by java.util

Comment: @user2121 u can't use this code for java .util timer check this tutorial http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm you need to do some changes

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that you should import which Timer class you will use. When you import javax.swing.Timer you specifies Timer class in javax.swing package. You can use it in your java file.

Anyway, have you tried not using static keyword with your timeStampListener?